# Rails exception not working for find_by query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

exception handling not working for find_by query in rails
  here the code :

```
  ab = User.find_by_uniq_token(params[:uniq_token])
```

not raise exeption ...while:

```
  ab = User.find(:id)  # is working fine...
```

i have exception handling code in application controller like:

```
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found


  def record_not_found
    if current_user
      flash[:notice] = "Record not found "
      redirect_to authenticated_root_url
   else
     flash[:notice] = "Record not found ."
     redirect_to unauthenticated_root_url
     # Assuming you have a template named 'record_not_found'
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use equivalent bang (`!`) methods to raise the exception if no record found.

```
ab = User.find_by_uniq_token!(params[:uniq_token])
```

**OR**

```
ab = User.where(uniq_token: params[:uniq_token]).first!
```